# Looping over certain files recursively which creating a directory inside each directory

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I wrote a simple bash script to convert video files. When run, it first makes `output` directory and then iterates over all `.mp4` files, converts them and puts the result to `output` directory.

```
mkdir output && for f in *.mp4; do echo $f; \
ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i $f -vf scale=1280:-2,fps=25 output/$f; done
```

I'd like to add to the script one feature: looping in all the sub-directories (but no the current directory itself), creating 'output` directory and executing conversion.

I managed to find all files meeting given criterion in all sub-directories by using this code:

```
for d in */; do
  for f in "$d"/*.mp4; do
    echo "$d"
    file="${f##*/}"
    echo "$file"
  done
done
```

The script prints the following, which is correct.

```
1/
01.mp4
2/
02.mp4
```

However, that's all I was able to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use find to search directories recursively.

```
$ find -mindepth 2 -type f ! -path '*/output/*' -name '*.mp4' \
  -exec bash -c 'mkdir -p "${1%/*}/output"; ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i "$1" -vf scale=1280:-2,fps=25 "${1%/*}/output/${1##*/}"' _ {} \;
```

Or a for loop with globstar:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar nullglob

for i in **/*.mp4; do
    if [[ $i != */output/* ]]; then
        mkdir -p "${i%/*}/output"
        ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i "$i" -vf scale=1280:-2,fps=25 "${i%/*}/output/${i##*/}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: `$ find -mindepth 2 -type f -name '*.mp4' -exec \
  bash -c 'ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i $1 -vf scale=1280:-2,fps=25 output/${1##*/}' _ {} \;
./pp/1-: No such file or directory`. I tried to use "$1" as files have spaces but it didn't work either.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "$1".

Comment: Now it prints `output/ok.mp4: No such file or directory`.

Comment: When I create output directory in a directory where an mp4 is located and then use `cd ..` and run your code, I still get that message.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't do the trick. I'm getting `: No such file or directory`.